# Finding Substring in 2D Array(Puzzle)

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, substring, puzzle

I have been trying to make a word puzzle(without using any library functions)like you would find in a newspaper like the following:

```
15 rows 12 colums
X T Z M Q Y K C E C F H -->12 chars 
S H O U T E X O E A P I
X G T L Q B E L T N F K
'
'
'
```

as you can see in the second row there is the word SHOUT. Now the puzzle is designed so that the user can input any sort of char set they want line by line.

What I want to do is when a word is searched (like SHOUT) I would return its starting index. The index I imagined will start at 0 and end at 180, as 12*15=180 like this to be clear:

```
X T Z M Q Y K C E C F H
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
S H O U T E X O E A P I
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
'
'
'
'''''''''''''''''''179
```

Its hard to explain it without a picture, I hope you understand.

Now the tricky thing is words can be in every direction (up to down, down to up, left to right, right to left). I have written most of the code but keep getting errors and it only can check if the word exists from left to right.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLUNM 12
#define ROW 15

int computeLength (char str[50]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    }
    return i;
}

int findString(char matrix[ROW][COLUNM], char string[], int length) {
    int i = 0, j, k = 0, searchlenght = 0;
    length = computeLength(string);

    for (j = 0; j < ROW; j++) {
        if (matrix[j][k] == string[k]) {
            searchlenght++;
        }
    }
    i++;
    if (searchlength == length) {
        return i;
    }
}

int main() {
    int i, j = 0;
    char matrix[ROW][COLUNM];
    char string[50];
    int b = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        printf("Enter line %d of the puzzle :\n", i + 1);       
        scanf("%s", &matrix[j][i]);
        j++;    
    }

    while (b > 0) {
        printf("Enter the string to be searched in the puzzle:\n");

        scanf("%s", &string[50]);
        if ((string[0] != 'q') || (string[0] != 'Q')) {
            b = 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't think this is so hard to implement with python but I'm so unfamiliar with C that I keep getting errors and warnings.

Only part that needs work is findString function. Don't bother with input as I will test it myself.

Could you please help?

**The only part that does not work is length=computeLength(str1); thşs when I enter computeLength("Shout") it returns 5 but in this piece of code it returns 2 which messes up the result **

```
int findString(char matrix[ROW][COLUNM],char str1[],int length){
int i,j,wordcounting;
int true=1;

length=computeLength(str1);
printf("%d",length);

for(j=0;j<ROW;j++){

if(matrix[i][j]==str1[0]){

    for(wordcounting=1;wordcounting<length;wordcounting++){

        if((matrix[i][j+wordcounting]!=str1[wordcounting])){
            true=0;
            break;

        }

    }
}
i++;}



if(true==1){return (i-length);}
}
```

When I say printf("%d",computeLength(string)); even before ı input a string it becomes 2

Comment: There are several things in your code that could be improved. Are you asking the fixes such that your code can be compiled or are you asking something else?

Comment: @CRM I m asking for the algorithm  .  I solved the error but if there is any way to do it better I m open to suggestions .The challenge was to make it without any other library functions. Right now the code does nothing basiclly

Comment: Just remove ",int computeLength(string[15])" in the line 29. Also line 39 remove "[15]". That will allow you to compile. I encourage you to reconsider "scanf("%s",&string[50]);" in *main*, and also the termination of the *while* containing that *scanf* if case the first char is not q nor Q. Your *findString* cannot work, reconsider how you manage *count*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a loooooooog answer where I explain the more I can your problems, how to solve them, and finally how to implement the search step by step up to a final solution.

Have a good reading !

---

There a lot of problems in your code, first it cannot be compiled.

The line 29 is invalid, replace

> ```
> int findString(char matrix[ROW][COLUNM],char string[15],int computeLength(string[15])){
> ```

by

```
int findString(char matrix[ROW][COLUNM], char string[15])
```

Note also the size 15 is useless you can use *char string[]* or *char * string* for the parameter *string*

The line 39 is invalid, replace

> ```
> if(count==computeLength(string[15])){
> ```

by

```
if(count==computeLength(string)){
```

Now you can compile your program, but this not enough.

---

Some problems in *main*.

You exchanged the indexes in the line

> ```
> scanf("%s",&matrix[j][i]);
> ```

It can be replaced by

```
scanf("%s",&matrix[i][0]);
```

(I used 0 rather than *j* because it is more clear, that does not ask us to check *j* values 0)

But this is not enough, *scanf* can read more than *COLUNM* characters if the input is invalid, and even the input is 12 characters as you expect you forget *scanf* will also write the null character finishing the string, so it writes 13 characters.

A way is to read in *string* which is longer than *COLUMN* more 2 and check the length of the input string. So your *for* can be replaced by :

```
for(i = 0 ; i < ROW ; i++)
{
  printf("Enter line %d of the puzzle :\n",i+1);       
  if ((scanf("%49s", string) != 1) ||
      (strlen(string) != COLUMN)) {
    puts("invalid line");
    return -1;
  }
  memcpy(&matrix[i][0], string, COLUMN);
  i++;    
}
```

Note also at the end *i* is incremented rather than *j*.

In the *while* loop

> ```
> scanf("%s",&string[50]);
> ```

is invalid because it will place the result after *string*, the index must be 0 and in fact you can just give *string*.

As before if the input as more than 49 characters *scanf* will write out of *string*, so do

```
scanf("%49s", string);
```

If you want to allow to search a string of 50 characters without counting the final null character you have to size it with 51 and replace 49 by 50.

Out of printing and reading the *while* loop does nothing, it is very probable you wanted to call *findString* in it and to write the returned value, until the first read character is q or Q. For instance :

```
 for (;;) {
   puts("Enter the string to be searched in the puzzle:");
   if ((scanf("%49s", string) != 1) || (string[0] =='q') || (string[0] == 'Q'))
     break;
   printf("position in the puzzle: %d\n", findString(matrix, string));
 }
```

At the end of *main* the interest of that line is obscure :

> ```
> printf("%d",computeLength("küfür"));
> ```

---

In *printPuzzle* you missed to introduce a newline after you print *PUZZLE*, you can just replace *printf* by *puts*. Note it is useless to ask *printf* to search for % etc while you know there is none.

---

In *findString*

A first problem is you only return a value if *count==computeLength(string)* is true, you need to always to return a value. Typically you can return -1 if the string is not in the puzzle, so

```
return (count==computeLength(string)) ? i : -1;
```

but this is wrong too, and for two reasons :

- when you reach the test *i* always value 180, not the position where the string was
- this is not because *count==computeLength(string)* is true that the string was found because of the way you used to increment *count* and the next error :

You do not search correctly the string in the puzzle because your first loop on *i* goes though the string (*string[i]*), and worst will access to 180 characters in it while its length is only 49 (without the final null character). You also do not stop to search even you find the string. And in your algorithm you forget the characters of string must be placed consecutively in the matrix, you each time you (wrongly) find a character of the string anywhere in the matrix you increment *count*.

Just considering you search the string horizontally from left to right :

- The loop on *string* must be the more embedded loop to check its characters are consecutive in the matrix.
- You have one loop on the row an one on the column, this is useless and just make  the job complex for nothing. Because *matrix* is an array the character at *matrix[r][COLUMN]* is the character at *matrix[r+1][0]*, that means you can go through *matrix* like it is a string of *ROW*COLUMN* characters.
- I let you rewrite *findString*, it is like *strstr* except you return the index or -1 rather than the address of the substring or NULL

---

[edit with proposal for the search functions]

To explain I will use that small matrix more easy to look at :

```
#define COLUMN 3
#define ROW 5

char Matrix[ROW][COLUMN] = { { 'a', 'b' , 'c' }, 
                             { 'd', 'e' , 'f' }, 
                             { 'g', 'h' , 'i' }, 
                             { 'j', 'k' , 'l' }, 
                             { 'm', 'n' , 'o' } };
```

Let start with searching from **left to right**, this is similar to the classic *strstr* function except the return value and there is a rollback at the end of the matrix. Let decide the value is -1 if the string is not found else the position of its first character times 1000 more the position of its last character. The definition can be :

```
int search_left2right(char * matrix, char * word)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i != ROW*COLUMN; ++i) {
    int j = i;
    char * w = word;

    while (*w == matrix[j]) {
      if (!*++w)
        return i * 1000 + j;
      if (++j == ROW*COLUMN)
        j = 0;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Compilation and execution with that main :

```
int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", search_left2right((char *) Matrix, "cde"));
  printf("%d\n", search_left2right((char *) Matrix, "noa"));
  printf("%d\n", search_left2right((char *) Matrix, "cdf"));
  return 0;
}

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
2004
13000
-1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

2004 if for 2 and 4, 13000 if for 13 and 0, the string is not found in the last case, this is ok

Searching from **right to left**.

A first obvious way is to reuse the previous function and to reverse the string before to search it. In case the string is found in the result the position of the first and last characters are just reversed too.

An other way is to iterate on the string to search in the reverse order, let choose that way.

Searching from **right to left or from left to right**.

To indicate the direction the parameter *wstep* is added and values 1 for left to right, else -1. The definition can be :

```
/* manual strlen, you want to define all string functions */
int strLen(char * s)
{
  char * p = s;

  while (*p)
    p += 1;
  return p - s;
}

int search_horiz(char * matrix, char * word, int wstep)
{
  int i;
  int wbegin = (wstep == 1) ? 0 : strLen(word) - 1;
  int wend = (wstep == 1) ? strLen(word) - 1 : 0;

  for (i = 0; i != ROW*COLUMN; ++i) {
    int j = i;
    int k = wbegin;

    while (word[k] == matrix[j]) {
      if (k == wend)
        return (wstep == 1) ? i * 1000 + j : j * 1000 + i;
      k += wstep;
      if (++j == ROW*COLUMN)
        j = 0;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Compilation and execution with that main :

```
int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", search_horiz((char *) Matrix, "cde", 1));
  printf("%d\n", search_horiz((char *) Matrix, "edc", -1));
  printf("%d\n", search_horiz((char *) Matrix, "noa", 1));
  printf("%d\n", search_horiz((char *) Matrix, "aon", -1));
  printf("%d\n", search_horiz((char *) Matrix, "cdf", 1));
  printf("%d\n", search_horiz((char *) Matrix, "fdc", -1));

  return 0;
}

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall m.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
2004
4002
13000
13
-1
-1
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Searching from **top to bottom**.

When we search from left to right we compare the characters from to string with the consecutive characters in the matrix (step is 1), more the roll back.

To search from top to bottom we do not have to look consecutive characters in the matrix, we want to stay in the same vertical so the step is *COLUMN*. Of course this is not the case when we are on the last line, in that case we go back on the first line and move to the right, except from the last character of the matrix where we have to rollback to the first character. The definition can be :

```
int search_top2down(char * matrix, char * word)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i != ROW*COLUMN; ++i) {
    int j = i;
    char * w = word;

    while (*w == matrix[j]) {
      if (!*++w)
        return i * 1000 + j;
      if ((j += COLUMN) >= ROW*COLUMN)
        j = (j - ROW*COLUMN + 1) % COLUMN;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Compilation and execution with that main :

```
int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", search_top2down((char *) Matrix, "dgj"));
  printf("%d\n", search_top2down((char *) Matrix, "knc"));
  printf("%d\n", search_top2down((char *) Matrix, "oad"));

  return 0;
}

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wall m.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
3009
10002
14003
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Searching **from left to right or from top to bottom**

But comparing *search_left2right* and *search_top2down* we can see they have almost the same definition, the only change is the value of the step in the matrix and the correction when the step cannot be applied alone. So it is possible to have:

```
int search_left2right_top2down(char * matrix, char * word, int step, int correct)
{
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i != ROW*COLUMN; ++i) {
    int j = i;
    char * w = word;

    while (*w == matrix[j]) {
      if (!*++w)
        return i*100 + j;
      if ((j += step) >= ROW*COLUMN)
        j = (j - ROW*COLUMN + correct) % COLUMN;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

To do left to right *step* is 1 and *correct* is 0, to do top to bottom *step* is COLUMN and correct is 1.

Searching in **all the four directions**

The needed modification to search from *bottom to top* from *top to bottom* are like it was to search *right to left* from *left to right*.

That means we can have easily only one search function managing left to right, right to left, top to bottom and bottom to top. For instance :

```
int search(char * matrix, char * word, int wstep, int step, int correct)
{
  int i;
  int wbegin = (wstep == 1) ? 0 : strLen(word) - 1;
  int wend = (wstep == 1) ? strLen(word) - 1 : 0;

  for (i = 0; i != ROW*COLUMN; ++i) {
    int j = i;
    int k = wbegin;

    while (word[k] == matrix[j]) {
      if (k == wend)
        return (wstep == 1) ? i * 1000 + j : j * 1000 + i;
      k += wstep;
      if ((j += step) >= ROW*COLUMN)
        j = (j - ROW*COLUMN + correct) % COLUMN;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

With that *main* compilation and execution :

```
int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "cde", 1, 1, 0));
  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "noa", 1, 1, 0));
  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "cdf", 1, 1, 0));

  putchar('\n');

  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "edc", -1, 1, 0));
  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "aon", -1, 1, 0));
  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "fdc", -1, 1, 0));

  putchar('\n');

  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "dgj", 1, COLUMN, 1));
  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "knc", 1, COLUMN, 1));
  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "oad", 1, COLUMN, 1));

  putchar('\n');

  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "jgd", -1, COLUMN, 1));
  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "cnk", -1, COLUMN, 1));
  printf("%d\n", search((char *) Matrix, "dao", -1, COLUMN, 1));

  return 0;
}

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall m.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
2004
13000
-1

4002
13
-1

3009
10002
14003

9003
2010
3014
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Let notice to give the 3 parameters to indicate how to process is not a pretty way, I used them because I considered it was better to have them to explain, but because there are always the same it is easy to improve :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COLUMN 3
#define ROW 5

/* manual strlen, you want to define all string functions */
int strLen(const char * s)
{
  const char * p = s;

  while (*p)
    p += 1;
  return p - s;
}

typedef struct SearchParameters {
  int wstep;
  int step;
  int correct;
} SearchParameters;

const SearchParameters Left2Right = { 1, 1, 0 };
const SearchParameters Right2Left = { -1, 1, 0 };
const SearchParameters Top2Bottom = { 1, COLUMN, 1 };
const SearchParameters Bottom2Top = { -1, COLUMN, 1 };

int search(const char * matrix, const char * word, SearchParameters how)
{
  int i;
  int wbegin = (how.wstep == 1) ? 0 : strLen(word) - 1;
  int wend = (how.wstep == 1) ? strLen(word) - 1 : 0;

  for (i = 0; i != ROW*COLUMN; ++i) {
    int j = i;
    int k = wbegin;

    while (word[k] == matrix[j]) {
      if (k == wend)
        return (how.wstep == 1) ? i * 1000 + j : j * 1000 + i;
      k += how.wstep;
      if ((j += how.step) >= ROW*COLUMN)
        j = (j - ROW*COLUMN + how.correct) % COLUMN;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}

/* */

typedef struct TestCase {
  const char * str;
  const SearchParameters * how;
  const char * strHow;
} TestCase;

void test(const char (*m)[3], const TestCase * tc)
{
  int r = search((char *) m, tc->str, *(tc->how));

  if (r == -1)
    printf("cannot found '%s' in '%s'\n", tc->str, tc->strHow);
  else
    printf("'%s' found in '%s', start at %d, end at %d\n",
           tc->str, tc->strHow, r / 1000, r % 1000);
}

int main()
{
  static const char matrix[ROW][COLUMN] = { { 'a', 'b' , 'c' }, 
                                            { 'd', 'e' , 'f' }, 
                                            { 'g', 'h' , 'i' }, 
                                            { 'j', 'k' , 'l' }, 
                                            { 'm', 'n' , 'o' } };
  static const TestCase tests[] = {
    { "cde", &Left2Right, "Left2Right" },
    { "noa", &Left2Right, "Left2Right" },
    { "cdf", &Left2Right, "Left2Right" },
    { "edc", &Right2Left, "Right2Left" },
    { "aon", &Right2Left, "Right2Left" },
    { "fdc", &Right2Left, "Right2Left" },
    { "dgj", &Top2Bottom, "Top2Bottom" },
    { "knc", &Top2Bottom, "Top2Bottom" },
    { "oad", &Top2Bottom, "Top2Bottom" },
    { "jgd", &Bottom2Top, "Bottom2Top" },
    { "cnk", &Bottom2Top, "Bottom2Top" },
    { "dao", &Bottom2Top, "Bottom2Top" }
  };

  int t;

  for (t = 0; t != sizeof(tests) / sizeof(TestCase); t += 1)
    test(matrix, &tests[t]);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall mm.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
'cde' found in 'Left2Right', start at 2, end at 4
'noa' found in 'Left2Right', start at 13, end at 0
cannot found 'cdf' in 'Left2Right'
'edc' found in 'Right2Left', start at 4, end at 2
'aon' found in 'Right2Left', start at 0, end at 13
cannot found 'fdc' in 'Right2Left'
'dgj' found in 'Top2Bottom', start at 3, end at 9
'knc' found in 'Top2Bottom', start at 10, end at 2
'oad' found in 'Top2Bottom', start at 14, end at 3
'jgd' found in 'Bottom2Top', start at 9, end at 3
'cnk' found in 'Bottom2Top', start at 2, end at 10
'dao' found in 'Bottom2Top', start at 3, end at 14
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Thank u so much this will help me code better in future. Btw I just assumed the user will input only valid things so did not bother at least I did while testing. I will try my best to findString work but if it doesn't can I count on you lol thanks

Comment: @uLas *never* trust on an input from a user, *always* check it.

Comment: I understand what u are trying to say and understand the logic behind it but I can't get findString to work.

Comment: @uLas is sad you did not found for all the 4 directions, did you at least success horizontaly from left to right ?

Comment: yes ı made it work for left to right and rigth to left

Comment: I just see you accepted my answer, but I do not know when because I was editing my answer to add a looooong description to do the search. I am still editing my answer to make the things a little more sexy, I will warn you by a new remark when I will finish

Comment: char * matrix, char * word, int wstep, int step, int correct I dont understand why we need these extra parameters I want to do it with 3  matrix,word, length of the word

Comment: I mean thank u so much this is brilliant but I was going for something much more simpler check the question I changed it

Comment: I really love the work you put in to help me but a noob like me can only write the way I wrote in the last section of the question. This was a challenge given by my teacher to test us and make a little rivarly with my friends. I cant even modify this to a simpler version my little brain is not working

Comment: @uLas about parameters, of course *matrix* is the matrix itself, *word* is the word/sentence to search in the matrix (in your ode you name it *string*), the other params are needed to say how to search in the string without having a dedicated function to search left to right, an other one for right to left etc. If you look at the end on my answer you will see only one parameter is used rather than the three

Comment: @uLas if I well understand in your edited question *findString* search from left to right, even I do not know if you want to manage the roolback. In my answer that function is named *search_left2right*, if you want to only get the begin position replace _return i * 1000 + j;_ by _return i;_ In my answer you also have calls to that function, look at it and compare with your function, which has a lot of problems inside. Use a debugger to execute step by step your solution and mine, that will help you to see how they work if needed

Comment: In my code   printf("%d",computeLength(string)) =2 no matter what I do thats where I got stuck. Computelength works correctly when  computeLength("Shout") but when ı say input =scanf("%s",&string[50]); and  printf("%d",computeLength(string)) it doesnt work

Comment: @uLas "*if(true==1){return (i-length);}*"  what happens when *true* does not value 1 ? As I already said you need to *always* return a value

Comment: @uLas out of the missing result, the *return* supposes *i* point just after the *string* in the matrix, so if you do not have the right return value that means *i* does not values what you expected, and yes this is the case. Typically when you find the string you have to return, but this is not what you do, that cannot work then. **Execute your code under a debugger** to follow its execution, of add *printf* inside to debug, and you will understand why that does not work. You can also compare with my version and execute it under a debugger too to understand how it works well

Comment: @uLas yes it works but why do you ask me to know ? just make a program containing its definition more *int main(){ printf("%d\n",  computeLength("aze")); return 0; }* and you will see if it works (printing 3) or not works (printing something else or nothing etc)

Comment: look I'm not asking for anything but if you want you can modify the code here https://onlinegdb.com/r1obgGfdU so that it would work. Thank u so much for trying to help me

Comment: I did but it works when printf("%d\n", computeLength("aze")) this is the case not when input is an char array printf("%d\n", computeLength(str)) it just gives 2 all the time

Comment: @uLas I so not understand what you say, look at https://onlinegdb.com/SklZNMfOL and if you want modify the input for other string. On which OS do you program (Windows, a Linux etc)

Comment: Ok I fixed it one last thing can u make it so that in the search fuction you wrote so that it doesnt have SearchParameters so that it just looks at every direction no matter what you entered ?

Comment: @uLas the only way to do that is close to duplicate 4 times the code of *search*, I will not do that because this is not the right way. All the work I did was to avoid dedicated *search* function. However you can add an other function getting the matrix and the string to search and that function calls *search* with the four possibilities, that is possible

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the compile error mentioned (and only the compile error), I suggest you do something like this:

```
int findString(char matrix[ROW][COLUNM],char string[15])
{

   int length = computeLength(string);

...
}
```

You can't have the way you declared the function like what you did.   Now slight further recommendation...

There is already a C function that can compute C string lengths:

```
#include <string.h> 
...
const char* string = "hello";

int length = strlen(string);
...
```

Comment: I know strlen Im trying to learn c so the challenge was to write all of the functions myself thank u